# Prove the following equality to show a relationship between Poisson and Gamma Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, poisson-distribution

I've been trying to do integration by parts on the following left side of this equation for the past half hour but my problem is that I cannot get rid of the Gamma variable.  For the left side, I see the resemblance to Poisson, but I'm not so sure how I can get rid of the summation sign.  Any ideas?  Here's the identity:

$$\int_{x}^{\infty} 1/\gamma(\alpha) z^{\alpha} e^{-z} dz=\sum_{n=0}^{\alpha-1} x^{y}e^{-x}/y!$$.  Let $\alpha=1, 2, etc...$

Also you can't really use integration by parts for the right side either...

Comment: Given $\alpha$, you have $\gamma(\alpha)$ as a normalising constant, so you can take it outside the integral.  What happens if you try integrating the left hand side by parts?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to comment, but your summation on the right-hand side doesn't make sense because the index $n$ isn't found anywhere in the summand and I don't think you're actually just summing that quantity an infinite number of times.

Comment: $n$ and $y$ may be the same thing